# Error with session variable

Tags: php

I seem to be getting an error in my PHP file.  It was working earlier but now it just doesn't seem to work

The error I get is:

> Notice: Undefined index: login_user in C:\wamp\www\catalogue.php on line 28

and Line 28 is:

```
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user'];?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Not sure why its giving me this error

The session `login_user` is created in a login page which is then called in the catalogue page. For some weird reason it seems to trigger whenever I try to empty my cart.

Comment: There is not a heckuva lot to go on here, but my bet is that `session_start()` isn't at the top of the page. That's just a guess since my crystal ball is out for maintenance. Can you share some more of the page's code?

Comment: Its the first thing i have just after an opening php tag
full code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBYgyg?editors=100

Comment: What sets `login_user`?

Comment: Thats set in a different file which stores the users usersname in the session. link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYqLxo?editors=100

Comment: @JayBlanchard its weird. i seem to get the error whenever i click on "empty cart"

Comment: You need to ask a new question with that as your issue. Make sure to include the relevant code in your question, not hosted at some other site.